# Static Method addStudents

Tags: java, oop, methods, constructor, static

So I need help with this part of JAVA in my COP class OOP programming.
First is that I need to change the addStudent to static method but the code will not run because the this.student is not static which makes no sense because it already private static

```
import java.util.Arrays; 
 
public class InitializerDemo { 
 
    public static final int MAX_STUDENTS = 10; 
     
    private static Student[] students; 
    private Instructor instructor; 
    private static int numStudents = 0; 
 
    // default constructor 
    public InitializerDemo() {
    
    } 
 
    // instructor mutator 
    public void setInstructor(Instructor instructor) { 
       this.instructor = instructor;
    } 
     
    // add a student, increment the count 
    //This PART!!! HELP
    public static void addStudent(Student s) { 
        this.students[numStudents++] = s;
    } 
     
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        // create our aggregator object 
        InitializerDemo id = new InitializerDemo(); 
         
        // set the instructor 
        id.setInstructor(new Instructor("Sally")); 
         
        // add the students 
        id.addStudent(new Student("Sam")); 
        id.addStudent(new Student("Rajiv")); 
        id.addStudent(new Student("Jennifer")); 
        id.addStudent(new Student("Test Student"));
        
        // output         
        System.out.println(id);   
    } 
     
    public String toString() { 
        String s = "Instructor = " + instructor + "\n" + 
                   "Number of students = " + numStudents + "\n" + 
                   "Students: " + Arrays.toString(students) + "\n"; 
        return s;   
    } 
}
```

```
class Student { 
 
    private String name; 
 
    // instance initializer block 
    { 
      name = "noname";  
    } 
     
    public Student() { 
        
    } 
     
    public Student(String name) { 
        this.name = name;  
    } 
     
    public String toString() { return name; }     
}
```

```
class Instructor { 
 
    private String name; 
 
    // instance initializer block 
    { 
      name = "noname";  
    } 
 
    public Instructor() { 
   
    } 
     
    public Instructor(String name) { 
      this.name = name;   
    } 
     
    public String toString() { return name; } 
}
```

I need help with that addStudent Method
These are the instructions and sorry to confuse all you guys and thank you for putting time to help me

change the instance variables representing the number of students and the Student array in the aggregator object to private static variables.

• change the addStudent method in the aggregator object from an instance method to a static method

• Remove all initialization/instantiation operations from the aggregator object’s default constructor; the constructor can simple be an empty method { }

• provide a static initializer block in the aggregator object which does the following:

o initializes the number of students to 0

o instantiates the student array

o adds a single student named “Test Student” to the array using the addStudent method

Comment: do you understand what the keyword "this" does?

Comment: `this.students` makes no sense in a `static` method. Specifically `this` has no meaning here. Simply write `students`.

Comment: Remove `static` from every single variable/method aside from `MAX_STUDENTS` and `main`. Don't add `static` as an access tool, it is more alike to a memory management tool.

Comment: no it works now but it shows this   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at InitializerDemo.addStudent(InitializerDemo.java:28)
 at InitializerDemo.main(InitializerDemo.java:39)

Comment: `students` is null. Doing `Student[] students;` is equivalent to `Student[] students = null;`

Comment: I know but it showing the exception over and over again

Comment: Well, without making `students` into something that isn't `null`, then you won't be able to do `students.something` nor `students[i]`, both will cause an NPE (NullPointerException).

Comment: but it wouldn't make sense to put something if the static array variable already contain the names in the main method with adding the names in the array. I'm sorry, I just confused by the program right now and it so frustrating as hell.

Comment: You can create an empty array, but Java arrays are fixed-sized (and won't dynamically make room for new elements). You likely want a `List<Student>` of some kind (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc).

Answer (score -1):

Change
`this.students[numStudents++] = s;`
to
`students[numStudents++] = s;`.
I believe that should work.

You also have to initialize the students, so change

```
private static Student[] students;
```

to

```
private static Student[] students = new Student[MAX_STUDENTS];
```

Comment: I tried that it gave this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at InitializerDemo.addStudent(InitializerDemo.java:28)
 at InitializerDemo.main(InitializerDemo.java:39)

Comment: you never initialized students, what else do you think would happen?

Comment: Instructor = Sally 
Number of students = 4 
Students: [Test Student, Sam, Rajiv, Jennifer, noname, noname, noname, noname, noname, noname] this was the expected output but why does it not print? but I need the student

Comment: Thanks but for the constructor part if I remove the default constructor it prints all the names with null, null, null, null but I want the noname except nulls